# Validation Error: The value 'on' is not valid for <<property name>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project, I have a model that you can see part of my model here:

```
public class CheckoutModel
{
    public bool OtherPlace { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("OtherPlace", true, ErrorMessage = " ")]
    public string OtherPlaceFullName { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("OtherPlace", true, ErrorMessage = " ")]
    public int OtherPlaceProvinceId { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("OtherPlace", true, ErrorMessage = " ")]
    public string OtherPlaceCity { get; set; }
}
```

I used **RequiredIf** attribute to validate my model in view,

```
 if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    }
```

I fill all property of my form but I get below validation error when **OtherPlaceProvinceId** is not filled.

**The value 'on' is not valid for OtherPlace.**

UPDATE: The controller is here:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CheckoutAccount()
    {
        var model = OrderManager.Instance.GetCheckoutAccount();
        return View("_CheckoutAccount", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckoutAccount(CheckoutAccountModel model)
    {
        return View("_CheckoutAccount", model);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your controller?

Comment: @mituw16 did you see my controller?

Comment: @mituw16, It works fine with Hadi Sharifi solution, Is there better solution?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You should change OtherPlaceProvinceId from int to int?,

```
public int? OtherPlaceProvinceId { get; set; }
```

Comment: This would only be needed if you can post a blank value for this field

Comment: This answer is pretty meaningless! How does it even relate to the problem mentioned in the answer??

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, the issue isn't with the integer, it's with the boolean. The browser is posting a checked value of "on" that the MVC ModelBinder is unable translate to a Boolean type

Answer (score 44):

Is OtherPlace a checkbox? The default value for a checkbox is `on` if it's ticked & blank if it's not. The ModelBinder doesn't understand this.

ASP.Net deals with this, if you use the helpers, by doing this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="OtherPlace" value="true"/>
<input type="hidden" name="OtherPlace" value="false"/>
```

The modelbinder will now figure out of the checkbox was ticked or not, convert it to a boolean & bind it to your model.

You could also use radio buttons with true/false values

Comment: In asp core, I didn't need to add the hidden field.

Comment: Or just use @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OtherPlace) in the view

Comment: yep, that's what I meant when I said "if you use the helpers"

Answer (score 1):

I'll do some workaround when you don't have too many inputs with this behavior.

It's simple, before you submit the form, catch the inputs with the **`'on'`** string and change it for the `true/false` value.

```
function toggle_validator(e) {
    if ($('#OtherPlace').val() == 'on') {
        $('#OtherPlace').val(true);
    }
    else {
        $('#OtherPlace').val(false);
    }
}
```

And we need to bind this event to the button that submit the form.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" onclick="toggle_validator();" />
```

Comment: This got me close, however, in my testing, $('#OtherPlace').val() was equal to 'true' not 'on', but otherwise, this solution worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my case and solution .. 
In my case I was passing the model to controller using jquery (Ajax post)..

```
<input type="checkbox" id="OtherPlace" name="OtherPlace" value="true"/>
```

the mistake was that I was getting "val()" of OtherPlace instead of Checked property

Wrong:

```
var otherPlace = $('#OtherPlace').val();
```

Correct:

```
var otherPlaces = $('#OtherPlace').prop('checked');
```

I hope this may help

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to assign value and also handle checked. 
As mentioned in other answers, the default value for a checkbox is "on" if checked and blank if not, but you can still override it.

Below I'm handling the checked attribute and also I assign a value. I am using bool? because this is what will normally lead you to this type of issues. If you are using bool type you can use tag helper instead.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myBoolField" name="myBoolField" value="@(Model.myBoolField??false)" @(Model.myBoolField??false == true? "checked:checked":"") />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myBoolField" name="myBoolField" value="true" @(Model.myBoolField??false == true? "checked":"") />
<input type="hidden" name="myBoolField" value="false" />
```